# Add custom required field validation on checkout page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am using [this](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date) extension to add custom field on checkout page.

Using [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259104/how-to-add-dropdown-in-checkout-page-after-shipping-method-in-magento-2) solution i have added my custom dropdown field in checkout.

All working fine till now.

Now i want to add required validation for my custom field. But i am not getting how to add.

[image]

If someone select Free shipping, Refer By option should be required and for other shipping method it should be optional.

**Update:** Here is the code that i am using to display dropdown

view\frontend\web\template\delivery-date-block.html

```
<label class="label">Delivery Date</label>
<div class="control">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datetimepicker: true"  name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<br/>
<label class="label">Comment</label>
<div class="control">
    <textarea name="delivery_comment" id="delivery_comment"></textarea>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<label class="label">Refer By</label>
<div class="control">

    <select name="refer_by" id="refer_by"
            class="input-select"
            data-bind="
                                  options: getCustomOption(),
                                  optionsValue: 'value',
                                  optionsText: 'label',
                                  optionsCaption: $t('---Select Store---'),
                                  value: customOptionValue">
    </select>
</div>
```

view\frontend\web\js\model\shipping-save-processor\default.js

```
/*global define,alert*/
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address'
    ],
    function (
        $,
        ko,
        quote,
        resourceUrlManager,
        storage,
        paymentService,
        methodConverter,
        errorProcessor,
        fullScreenLoader,
        selectBillingAddressAction
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            saveShippingInformation: function () {
                var payload;

                if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
                    selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
                }

                payload = {
                    addressInformation: {
                        shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                        billing_address: quote.billingAddress(),
                        shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                        shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                        extension_attributes:{
                            delivery_date: $('[name="delivery_date"]').val(),
                            delivery_comment: $('[name="delivery_comment"]').val(),
                            store_pickup: $('[name="store_pickup"]').val(),
                        }
                    }
                };

                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

                return storage.post(
                    resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
                    JSON.stringify(payload)
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                        paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response.payment_methods));
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        errorProcessor.process(response);
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }
);
```

view\frontend\web\js\view\delivery-date-block.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'SR_DeliveryDate/delivery-date-block',
            customOptionValue: ''
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var disabled = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.disabled;
            var noday = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.noday;
            var hourMin = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMin);
            var hourMax = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMax);
            var format = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.format;
            if(!format) {
                format = 'yy-mm-dd';
            }
            var disabledDay = disabled.split(",").map(function(item) {
                return parseInt(item, 10);
            });

            ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                    var $el = $(element);
                    //initialize datetimepicker
                    if(noday) {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format,
                            hourMin: hourMin,
                            hourMax: hourMax
                        };
                    } else {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format,
                            hourMin: hourMin,
                            hourMax: hourMax,
                            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var day = date.getDay();
                                if(disabledDay.indexOf(day) > -1) {
                                    return [false];
                                } else {
                                    return [true];
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    $el.datetimepicker(options);

                    var writable = valueAccessor();
                    if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                        var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                        if (propWriters && propWriters.datetimepicker) {
                            writable = propWriters.datetimepicker;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    writable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));
                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
                    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                    if (widget) {
                        var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        widget.date(date);
                    }
                }
            };

            return this;
        },
        initObservable: function () {

            this._super()
                .observe([
                    'customOptionValue'
                ]);
            return this;
        },
        getCustomOption: function() {
            return _.map(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.customOptionValue, function(value, key) {
                return {
                    'value': key,
                    'label': value
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What are the other changes required to save this custom field except adding field in Install scheme?

Comment: your issue is resolved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify **app/code/SR/DeliveryDate/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'SR_DeliveryDate/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'
        }
    },
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'SR_DeliveryDate/js/mixin/shipping-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/SR/DeliveryDate/view/frontend/web/js/mixin/shipping-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({

            /**
             * Set shipping information handler
             */
            setShippingInformation: function () {
                var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();
                if (shippingMethod['method_code'] == 'freeshipping') {
                    if ($("#custom_option").val() == '') {
                        this.focusInvalid();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                this._super();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello Sohel, It is almost working well. But one small issue. It's not adding error message to "custom_option" dropdown when it is not selected with freeshipping method.

Comment: @Hardik did you find solution to show error message?

Comment: That isn't working for me on v2.3.5 it load fine and console.log('here') as it loads, but when the button next is clicked in the checkout I've set another console.log('setShippingInformation') method but does not trigger, anyone knows why?